# Why is grails trying to download dependency versions of working@mymachinename?

Tags: maven, grails, artifactory

I have an existing (working) Grails 2.2.2 application. I am attempting to upgrade a dependency to a newer version. When I do this, the build fails with errors stating...

```
Failed to resolve dependencies
- com.google.guava:guava:working@mymachinename
- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:working@mymachinename
```

I am really confused as to why Grails is looking for artifacts with a version of 'working@mymachinename'

I am on a private network with its own hosted Artifactory. My BuildConfig.groovy identifies Artifactory and I have successfully pulled in resources in the past.

BuildConfig.groovy

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo name: myRepo, root: <artifactoryUrl>
}
dependencies {
    runtime 'com:mydependency:1.0'
}
```

I can browse Artifactory and find both missing resources but with valid version numbers, 14.0.1 and 2.2.0-b10 respectively.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Why is grails trying to download dependency versions of working@mymachinename?

Comment: what version of Grails are you trying to upgrade to?

Comment: are the 2 mentioned dependencies direct/transitive dependencies? did you try the dependency report command for getting more info?

Comment: What are direct/transitive dependencies? How do you run the dependency report?

Comment: By direct dependency I mean one your app depends on. A transitive are libraries that your own dependencies require, and are being included automatically. For more about the dependency report look at http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html

Comment: They are transitive dependencies. It looks like my maven repository did not contain some of these dependencies' parent POMs. When added, everything builds. Thanks. I still wonder why the error message with the weird versions? Where did "working@" version names come from?

Comment: I guess it is related somehow to the fact that Grails replaced the dependency resolution engine to aether, but don't have enough information to nail it

Comment: Just for reference, i have the same problem in SBT.